# Using dict.get to conditionally assign keys for nested dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I'm writing a loop to import 20 .json files. I want to create a dictionary of 20 dictionaries. I have everything except I need to conditionally use one of two fields to assign the 20 dictionary names (i.e., the 20 keys in the top-level dictionary).

The last two lines of my loop are:

```
name=jsondat.get('Info', {}).get('Name')
dict1[name] = text_dict
```

The `name` line works great except `['Info']['Name']` does not exist in all 20 .json files. In these cases I'm hoping to use a regular expression to extract a substring from a different field in `['Info']`. For the sake of brevity, let's just say I want to use a field named `'URL'`. So it seems like I need to do something like:

```
name=jsondat.get('Info', {}).get('Name','URL')
dict1[name] = text_dict
```

But that doesn't work. It runs, but it doesn't actually use the `'URL'` field when `'Name'` is not available.

Comment: The second argument to `dict.get` is a default *return value*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like

```
info = jsondat.get('Info', {})
name = info.get('Name', info.get('URL', None))
```

Which would use the value for 'Name' if it exists, otherwise it looks for 'URL', otherwise it just returns None.